# Android Life Cycles — Why can't onResume() be called in onPause(){ }?

Tags: android, android-lifecycle, onresume, onpause

This question is entirely theoretical. I don't see any practical application, just for understanding, but...

I'm trying to figure out a way to break the Life Cycle system to force my app to be Active and Visible at all times (like even when the home button is pressed) so I'm calling onResume() in onPause() and onRestart() in onStop() etc..

I'd expect the app to restart when I press the home button but obviously the Android OS is smarter than I. What is blocking the app from restarting itself?  Is there a way around it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the better way would be to call:

```
startActivity(new Intent(this, YourActivity.class));
finish();
```

inside onPause() (but all of these are pretty bad ideas)

Answer (score 2):

Calling onResume does not mean your app will resume. These functions are called when respective action happens. They don't make it happen (like destructor).

All life cycle methods are called by the system to, in a way, let you know something happened so that you can make appropriate changes. If you call `onResume` in `onPause`, it would just execute that method.